# Solve $(2\ln y - \ln(y)^2)dy = ydx - xdy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having problems with this ODE:

$$(2\ln y - \ln(y)^2)dy = ydx - xdy$$

Doesn't seem to be separable and I don't know what kind change of variables could be done

Comment: It is also much simpler to solve for the function x(y) and by simplifying the RHS to have dx/dy.

Answer (score 0):

Left hand side vanishes. Integrating, $ y = C x.$

Answer (score 0):

When you have a first order non-linear differential equation you can always try and see if you can solve it as an [exact differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactFirst-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html), which is of the form

$$
p(x,y) dx + q(x,y) dy = 0. \tag{1}
$$

By factoring out $dx$ and $dy$, one can obtain the following differential equation, such that $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ can be identified

$$
\underbrace{y}_{p(x,y)} dx + \underbrace{\left(\log(y)^2 - 2 \log(y) - x\right)}_{q(x,y)} dy = 0. \tag{2}
$$

For a exact differential equation is should be that

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}, \tag{3}
$$

but is currently not that case, since $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} = 1\right) \neq \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} = -1\right)$. However by multiplying the entire equation by some yet unknown function $\mu(x,y)$ it might become true.

In order to find $\mu(x,y)$ you can make use of the effect of the partial derivative, such that the complicated expression in $y$, $\log(y)^2 - 2 \log(y)$, vanishes in $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$. If the unknown function would only be a function of $y$, then this will still be the case. The remaining relevant parts of $q(x,y)$ and $p(x,y)$ are linear and only differ in sign one trial function would be $\mu(x,y) = y^p$. The value for $p$ can be found by using $(3)$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \mu(x,y)\ p(x,y) = (p+1) y^{p},
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mu(x,y)\ q(x,y) = -y^p,
$$

$$
(p+1) y^{p} = -y^p. \tag{4}
$$

From $(4)$ it can be derived that $\mu(x,y) = y^{-2}$. The solution to the differential equation can now be found by integrating the two terms and omitting double expressions

$$
\frac{x - \log(y)^2}{y} = c, \tag{5}
$$

where $c$ is the constant of integration.